# In PHP script instruct file to be opened in Sublime Text

Tags: php, bash, shell, sublimetext3

The following command opens foo.js in Sublime Text if executed directly in terminal:

```
$ subl /var/www/abcproj/js/foo.js
```

But trying this in PHP (PHP-FPM + Nginx server) does nothing:

```
exec('subl /var/www/abcproj/js/foo.js');
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because of on http request there is php interpreted by user www-data.

Try using a command line. It should work.

You can also set up the server by the command as a current user:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

In my case, it works.

Comment: If somebody vote on the minus, please explain what is wrong with my answer. Sending minus without any explanation is not useful for anyone.